# How can I check results for select statement in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Hi this is the SP I have :

```
  USE [Tracker_Entities]

  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO

  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspHub]

  @id int
  AS
  BEGIN

  SELECT DISTINCT table1.UID, table1.url, Scope.ID
  FROM         table1 INNER JOIN
            Scope ON table1.UID = Scope.newBrand
  WHERE     (table1.value = 0) AND (Scope.ID = @id)
  ORDER BY table1.url
  END

  GO
```

When i run this SP in sql server by passing ID as parameter i am getting expected result. Now I need to check this SP in mvc. This is the way I am calling this SP in my MVC :

```
using (var ctx = new database_Entities())
        {
            int ID = 122;
            ctx.uspHub(ID);

            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
```

But when I put breakpoint in **using** statement and check for results, it is not displaying any results. I am struggling here for long time and i am not getting proper solution for this. So what are the steps in MVC to check results for SP which has select statements??

**Update :** 
I got solution for this after using tolist. Now i am getting three results in list and i need to grab one result that is URL and pass it as input parameter. 
My code :
               int ID = 413;
                var x = ctx.uspdHub(ID).ToList();

Here x has 3 results. I need to take one result from it.I tried doing x. but it doesn't show results after i type dot. How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `Get` the result into proper `model`/`object`.

```
    List<YourEntity> model;
    using (var ctx = new database_Entities())
    {
        int ID = 122;
        model = ctx.uspHub(ID).toList();

        //ctx.SaveChanges(); - no need to call SaveChanges
                            // - as you are not updating anything

    }
```

Go through this article if you need more info. **[Call Stored Procedure From Entity Framework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/call-store-procedure-from-entity-framework/)** (The code above will work anyways...)

Comment: Hi now i have one more doubt.If possible can you help me? I can see three results now in my list. I need take one result from that say URL. I am trying to write like this :  var x = ctx.uspHub(ID).toList();.Now to take result, i am writing x.add().will this work??

Comment: There is one way... Try and check it out!! :) You will learn very quickly in this way.. :)

Comment: @christiandev: he is doing `var x = ctx.uspHub(ID).ToList();` - `ToList()`.... So... obviously... :)

Comment: @Paritosh yeah you are correct and i got to know how to select particular result.

Comment: @Paritosh, I just looked at `x.Add()`...my bad!

Answer (score 0):

use...

```
using (var ctx = new database_Entities())
        {
            int ID = 122;
            var result = ctx.uspHub(ID);
         }
```

and add a **break** after the `result` to see whats in the `result` variable. Obviously, the sope of result will need to be moved, but I'm only showing here how you can see the data returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
using (var dataContext= new database_Entities())
        {
            int ID = 122;
            SomeEntity[] result = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<SomeEntity>("[dbo].[uspHub] @id",new SqlParameter("@id", ID)).ToArray();
        }
```

It is good for me. I have used ORM EntityFramework to connect with DB.